# Trigger a Cloud Function and take action when function completes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an application where the web ui (react) Cloud Function then runs and updates a completion value in the database.

How can I show a 'progress' indication and take it down when the Cloud Function has completed?

I initially thought I would do something like this pseudo code with Promises:

```
return updateDatabaseToTriggerFunctionExec()
    .then listenForFunctionDoneEvent()
    .then return Promise.resolve();
```

However, I'm not sure how to know when the function has finished and updated a value.  What is the recommended way to detect when a triggered Cloud Function has completed?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement something like a command-response model using the database as a relay where you push commands into a location and the function pushes results out that can be listened to by the client that issued the command.  The thing that makes this work is the fact that the locations of the commands and responses and known between the client and server, and they have a common knowledge of the push id that was generated for the client command.

I go over this architecture a bit during [my session at Google I/O 2017](https://youtu.be/eWj6dxfN63g) where I build a turn-based game with Firebase.

An alternative is to use a HTTP function instead, which has a more clearly-defined request-response cycle.

Comment: Does firebase allow 'listening' to nodes that don't yet exist using ref.on() or ref.once() or is an existing node required which would then check to see if a child existed?

Comment: Nodes are never required to exist for any operation.

Comment: I wrote snippets for these "wait for value" situations a while ago: https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f. The JavaScript version: `var listener = ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('Value is now '+snapshot.val());
        ref.off('value', listener);
    }
});`

Comment: This is a good start.  In the general case it is possible for the firebase function to error out and not update the response as expected.  In this case a timeout is also required to provide a reject response.  I ended up wrapping it all with a 'timeout promise' that fires if no response is forthcoming.